# Excel OLEDB connection issue

Tags: vba, oledbconnection

Below is the code: What I am trying to do is made the refresh of data more under my control. So when I "GL date" from 03/31/2014 to 04/31/2014. The connection picks up the april data.

The error I am getting is With Selection.QueryTable, thats where it breaks.
The table starts at cell "A1" on the PCAP tab

```
    Sub Update()

    Call ReplaceConnectionandRefresh1("PCAP", "zzFS - PCAP- SCRF3", "Apollo", "zzFS - PCAP- SCRF3")

 End Sub


 Sub ReplaceConnectionandRefresh1(spreadsheet As Variant, DriverName As String, RWFolder As String, CombinedNumber As String)

    Sheets(spreadsheet).Visible = True
    Sheets(spreadsheet).Select
    Sheets(spreadsheet).Range("A1").Select
    With Selection.QueryTable
        .Connection = "OLEDB;Provider=ftiRSOLEDB.RSOLEDBProvider;" _
                    & "Integrated Security=" & """" & """" _
                    & ";Location=" & dbName & ";User ID=" & """" & """" _
                    & ";Initial Catalog=" & dbName & ";Data Source=" & ServerName _
                    & ";Mode=Read;Persist Security Info=True;Extended Properties="
        .MaintainConnection = False
         MYCURRENTVALUE = .CommandText
    End With
    MYCURRENTVALUE = """" & dbName & """"
    MYCURRENTVALUE = MYCURRENTVALUE & "." & """" & RWFolder & """"
    MYCURRENTVALUE = MYCURRENTVALUE & "." & """" & DriverName & """"

    MYCURRENTVALUE = MYCURRENTVALUE & " "
    MYCURRENTVALUE = MYCURRENTVALUE & """" & "Legal Entity=" & CombinedNumber & """"
    MYCURRENTVALUE = MYCURRENTVALUE & " " & """"


    MYCURRENTVALUE = MYCURRENTVALUE & "GL Date=" & Format("03/31/2014", "mm/dd/yyyy") & """"


    MYCURRENTVALUE = MYCURRENTVALUE & " FLAGS[/SILENT] "

    With Selection.QueryTable
        .CommandText = MYCURRENTVALUE
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Does `Selection.ListObject.QueryTable` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the range "A1" does not contain the Query table object. Also try to use Selection and Select as little as possible (Actually you will need it in very rare occasions) Rather use the actual object.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Update()

    Call ReplaceConnectionandRefresh1("PCAP", "zzFS - PCAP- SCRF3", "Apollo", "zzFS - PCAP- SCRF3")

 End Sub


Sub ReplaceConnectionandRefresh1(spreadsheet As String, _
                                 DriverName As String, _
                                 RWFolder As String, _
                                 CombinedNumber As String)

    Dim oQueryTable As QueryTable
    Dim strConnnection As String
    Dim strCommand As String

    ' Grab the query Table from the sheet. I am grabbing the first one
    ' adjust if there is more.
    Set oQueryTable = Sheets(spreadsheet).QueryTables(1)


    Sheets(spreadsheet).Visible = True
    Sheets(spreadsheet).Select
    Sheets(spreadsheet).Range("A1").Select

    ' Create connection string
    strConnnection = "OLEDB;Provider=ftiRSOLEDB.RSOLEDBProvider;" _
                     & "Integrated Security=" & """" & """" _
                     & ";Location=" & dbName & ";User ID=" & """" & """" _
                     & ";Initial Catalog=" & dbName & ";Data Source=" & ServerName _
                     & ";Mode=Read;Persist Security Info=True;Extended Properties="

    'Create connection command
    strCommand = """" & dbName & """"
    strCommand = strCommand & "." & """" & RWFolder & """"
    strCommand = strCommand & "." & """" & DriverName & """"
    strCommand = strCommand & " "
    strCommand = strCommand & """" & "Legal Entity=" & CombinedNumber & """"
    strCommand = strCommand & " " & """"
    strCommand = strCommand & "GL Date=" & Format("03/31/2014", "mm/dd/yyyy") & """"
    strCommand = strCommand & " FLAGS[/SILENT] "

    ' Actually update the connection.
    With oQueryTable
        .Connection = strConnnection
        .MaintainConnection = False
        .CommandText = strCommand
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

End Sub
```

Also note that there is a variable "dbName" that is not declared or passed as argument.

I hope this helps :)